# Registering codec at HttpHandler constructor fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor, ihttphandler

I have a handler as below. I want to Register the codec only once, so I added the code to register in the constructor.
It works for the first time, but it gives an error afterwards.
Error: *System.ArgumentException was unhandled. An item with the same key has already been added.*

```
public class DICOMHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public DICOMHandler()
    {
        Dicom.Codec.JpegLs.DcmJpegLsCodec.Register(); 
        Dicom.Codec.Jpeg.DcmJpegCodec.Register();
        Dicom.Codec.Jpeg2000.DcmJpeg2000Codec.Register();
        Dicom.Codec.DcmRleCodec.Register();
     }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
         //some code here
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to register the codec in the IHttpHandler?

Comment: The constructor will run each time a request is made if you want it to run only once per process make the constructor static.

Comment: Works great. Similarly, I have another class which has parametrized constructors. Is making that static advisable?

Comment: No static constructors must be parameterless as you can't call them explicitly.